# Grant permission to an app to interact with SSMS regardless of the user permission

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, ssms

I have a python application that interacts with the database (create/delete tables, insert/delete records). Therefore, It should have a high permission on SQL management studio.

What I would like to do is for the application to be able to interact with the DB regardless of the user permission.

I created an application role and assign it to the app. I know that the application role is activated because it used to cause some problems (which I could solve).

but I still have a big issue that is the app still relies on the user logins, so anyone with not enough permission is not able to use the code.

Here is part of the python code where the connection with the server is established:

```
server = '*****'
database = '*****'
driver = 'SQL+Server'
connection_string = 'mssql+pyodbc://%s/%s?driver=%s?        trusted_connection=true' % (server, database, driver)
engine = create_engine(connection_string, pool_recycle=-1, echo=False)
metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
role = 'Python_app'
role_password = '******'
session.execute("EXEC sp_setapprole '%s', '%s'" % (role, role_password))
```

[On this link a screenshot of the application role can be found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPd9w.png)

I have tried a lot of different things but I was not able to solve the problem. 
I will be glad if someone could point me out in the right direction.

Comment: Not sure if it'll work for you but have you considered having your app interact with only stored procedures in the db? This way you can have 'EXECUTE AS OWNER' in them to not worry about permissions and you also get much more control over what users can do. One sp for create table, one for delete, etc...

Comment: On an unrelated note: can't you pass those arguments to the query without string formatting? Not sure about pyodbc, but perhaps `session.execute("EXEC sp_setapprole ?, ?", (role, role_password))`, or use the SQLA `text()` wrapper for DBAPI agnostic placeholder handling. This may seem like nitpicking, but it's better not to make a habit out of passing stuff to SQL queries with string formatting – with the added benefit of not having to worry about quoting!